# Repair Vim editor

Tags: vim, editor, gvim

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have some troubles with Vim editor. First I was using the normal version preinstalled with Ubuntu, then I installed VI Improved from Ubuntu Software Center, with some plugins for working with Python.

Everything was fine until I installed GVim again from Ubuntu Software Center. I liked that version because it has a menu bar, I can launch GVim from the Unity dock, etc. Then I uninstall VI Improved from Ubuntu Software Center because I thought it didn't has sense to have it installed, I also move `usr/share/vim` folder to my home folder because I thought that was the folder containing GVim files (the one I wanted to use) and almost every plugins are installed in that path.

I really really screwed up, I installed and reinstalled, erased and restored files and Vim packages looking for the solution, now when I open GVim, it doesn't show the menu bar, the highlighting doesn't work too, I try to run `:Explore` command and it gives me E492 error (It is not an editor order: Explore), also the autocomplete is not working.

What do you guys recommend me? I want GVim working right again with my vim folder to install plugins, and `.vimrc` file to customize it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try reinstalling GVim:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-common vim-runtime
```

In particular, I think you need the `*-common` and `*-runtime` package files.

Comment: It woooorks !! thank you so much !, now where is the folder and .vimrc file ??

Comment: Which folder? Your vimrc file would be wherever you left it, since package installation doesn't touch files in your home directory.

Comment: Thank you your right I've installed Jedi plugin for python and everything seems to work perfectly!