# I can not use vim to edit texts

Tags: vim

The problem is that when I'm trying to edit text like:

```
>> vim lab
```

nothing happens. Can anyone help me?.

Comment: Sorry this is vague. Do you have `vim` installed?  is it you can't run it (nothing happens)?, or it starts and you don't know how to use it? (ie. it starts in command mode and you expect it to be in text-entry mode)  More info on your issue would help us to help you.

Comment: I could solve the problem that anything hapenned when I tried the example given. Now it opens the command mode, as always... But now the problem is that when I want, for example, to begin inserting text, normally it appears insert in the bottom part of the command mode... the problem is that it doesnt appears... I've seen that this issue is fixed by only making sudo apt-get update, and sudo apt-get install vim, but ive done that and the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

in case vim is not installed do:

```
sudo apt-get vim
```

if you stilll have issues do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-common vim-runtime
```

from : [Repair Vim editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589125/repair-vim-editor)

this fixed some issues I had

Also there are many vim questions around, Google more. There is a lot of support.

vim's website: https://www.vim.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter insert mode before you can actually start editing the document. You can do this by pressing `i` or `a`

```
i
```

It starts inserting at the current position of the cursor

```
a
```

It starts inserting after the current position of the cursor.